# Оператор SELECT

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

Всем добрый вечер. Насколько мне известно оператор SELECT выполняется в следующем порядке: FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY.

Почему мы можем в GROUP BY указывать столбцы их номерами из SELECT, как это сделано в указанном примере с codeacademy? К тому же в этом примере столбец создается только в результате выполнения SELECT, как оператор группирует по нему на предшествующем этапе?

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN elevation < 500 THEN 'Low'
        WHEN elevation BETWEEN 500 AND 1999 THEN 'Medium'
        WHEN elevation >= 2000 THEN 'High'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS elevation_tier
    , COUNT(*)
FROM airports
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Для какой СУБД написан этот запрос?

Comment: На codeacademy используется SQLite. (Добавил в метки)

Comment: Я думаю, что это не очень хороший способ обучаться, используя нестандартный диалект. Разве что с sqlite и работать.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko, многие сервера поддерживают такой синтаксис. Сходу могу вспомнить Firebird и Paradox.

Comment: Я это понимаю, но есть стандарт языка и такое понятие, как переносимость кода. Следование стандарту повышает переносимость. Что касается данного запроса, то ничего не стоит переписать его в рамках стандарта, и я уверен, что sqlite не будет возражать. :-)
И, кстати, тогда вопрос потеряет смысл. :-))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указанный порядок выполнения частей запроса только примерный. Для общего понимания процессов. Выражения в части select могут вычисляться на разных этапах. Было бы правильнее считать, что часть select выполняется одновременно с group by. Когда мы пишем:

```
select x, max(a), sum(b),
       sum(case when a=1 then 0 else b)
  from table
 group by x
```

БД не может выполнить ни одну из операций представленных в select ни до group by, так как она еще не знает в каком разрезе получать значения агрегатных функций. И не может выполнить ни одну из этих операций по уже собранным group by строкам, так как значения конкретных колонок записей до группировки уже не доступны. В приведенном примере все вычисления (включая сложные формулы внутри агрегатных функций) должны выполнятся над изначальными строками данных. group by лишь указывает в какой момент надо прекращать накопление данных (по отсортированным в порядке ключа group by записям) и начинать считать с начала. А так как это происходит на одной стадии, то почему бы не дать возможность программисту укороченный способ указания ключа.

P.S. на самом деле в SQLite, в отличие от многих других СУБД, позволяются и более не мыслимые с точки зрения строго порядка операций, вещи. Например, `select max(X) from table group by Y having Z=max(Z)` вернет из каждой группы Y максимальные X среди записей, у которых Z равен максимальному Z для группы. Записи где Z не равен максимальному рассматриваться не будут. Что бы выполнить такой фукус СУБД сначала надо получить максимумы для групп, не сворачивая записи в одну, после чего отобрать только подходящие записи и наконец выполнить группировку до конца, оставив только итоговые строки. Так что выходит, что в SQLite и having выполняется не совсем после group by ...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы рекомендовать источник, где был бы с некоторой точностью изображен алгоритм исполнения оператора?

Comment: @AkariGale Нет, таких источников не припомню. Смотрите техническую документацию от производителей БД и статьи по оптимизации запросов, там периодически раскрывают некоторые внутренние механизмы.

Comment: Насколько я помню, выполнение идет примерно так: FROM -> SELECT1 -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT2 -> ORDER BY, где SELECT1 - вычисление столбцов, которые нужны для GROUP BY, а SELECT2 - вычисление остальных. Во всяком случае в некоторых серверах так.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов select1 перед where это странно. зачем вычислять значения столбцов для строк, которых не будет в итоге т.к. их выбросят условия where.

Comment: @Mike, может я и напутал. А может там еще сложнее. FROM -> SELECT_for_WHERE -> WHERE -> SELECT_for_GROUP_BY -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT_OTHER -> ORDER BY

Comment: @ГерманБорисов А что такое select_for_where, понятно что записи для where выбираются, вернее он как раз определяет какие записи и в каком порядке брать. Только это "select" называть уже как то неправильно. По структуре запроса "select" стоит называть фазу вычисления значений в части select. И вообще порядка, указанного в вопросе для общего понимания достаточно, а то что по факту оптимизатор может переставить все с ног на голову, так это его дело. В конце концов, оптимизатор даже order by может начать выполнять в самом начале, выбирая записи в порядке индекса а потом делая остальную обработку